# Compiling MATLAB 2009b applications to Windows Executables

Tags: compiler-construction, matlab, versioning

Does anyone know how to add full (n.n.n.n) Windows file version information to COM dlls and .Net Assemblies compiled from MATLAB? The resulting dlls do not seem to contain a VersionInfo structure and so utilities like Resource Hacker don't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The -W option to MCC allows specifying a major and minor version, but not the build number.

```
mcc -W 'component_type:component_name,class_name,major.minor'
```

I'm not sure if this is sufficient to at least put the version resource in place so, to allow editing with some other tool.

Comment: I do need the full n.n.n.n version info but I will try that to see if it creates a Winodws version structure. Thanks.